# How to make the time from len of array

Tags: python

How to make time from len of array...

Picture 1:
[image]

Picture 2:
[image]

How to make the picture 1 as picture 2

Picture 1 come from below:

`

```
x=[]
colors=['red','green','brown','teal','gray','black','maroon','orange','purple']
colors2=['green','red','orange','black','maroon','teal','blue','gray','brown']
for i in range(0,1950):
    x.append(i)
for i in range(0,1):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
    # plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,out[0:1950,i],color=colors[i])
    plt.plot(x,predictions[0:1950,i],markerfacecolor='none',color=colors2[i])
    plt.title('LSTM Regression (Training Data)')
    plt.ylabel('Force/Fz (N)')
    plt.xlabel('Time/s')
    plt.legend(['Real value', 'Predicted Value'], loc='upper right')
    plt.savefig('Regression Result.png'[i])
    plt.show()
```

`

Comment: Can you add more details? What do you actually want to do? What are the steps to get pic 1 from pic 2? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to make the time from x, so the size of array x is 1950. then x data  is taken for 40s.     In this case I want change 0:1950 to 0-40s as the picture 2. the picture 2 is just the example as I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ahrensaj's answer makes sense.

Here is your code modified to rescale the time scale.

```
x=[]
colors=['red','green','brown','teal','gray','black','maroon','orange','purple']
colors2=['green','red','orange','black','maroon','teal','blue','gray','brown']
# just update the x with correct scaling; use numpy array for faster computations
x = numpy.arange(0,1950)*40/1950 
for i in range(0,1):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
    # plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,out[0:1950,i],color=colors[i])
    plt.plot(x,predictions[0:1950,i],markerfacecolor='none',color=colors2[i])
    plt.title('LSTM Regression (Training Data)')
    plt.ylabel('Force/Fz (N)')
    plt.xlabel('Time/s')
    plt.legend(['Real value', 'Predicted Value'], loc='upper right')
    plt.savefig('Regression Result.png'[i])
    plt.show()
```

EDIT:
@minn's comment made me curious about `np.linspace` vs `np.arange`. I often use `np.arange` and divide appropriately because it is one less command to remember. In any case, I benchmarked the two. `np.arange` seems to do better.

```
In [8]: %time [np.linspace(0,40,1950) for _ in range(10)]
CPU times: user 1.81 ms, sys: 146 µs, total: 1.96 ms
Wall time: 1.6 ms
```

```
In [9]: %time [np.arange(0,1950)/40 for _ in range(10)]
CPU times: user 794 µs, sys: 55 µs, total: 849 µs
Wall time: 1.09 ms
```

Comment: Might be better to use `np.linspace(0, 40, 1950)`

Comment: @Minn Just updated with a comparison between `linspace` and `arange`

Answer (score 1):

Your x array is essentially just a number of iterations. The iteration number divided by whatever your time step is should give you time, so when calling `plt.plot()` use `x/dt` instead of x